# Cytoscape Desktop: Order of source nodes if group attributes layout is applied by target node attribute

Tags: cytoscape

I am using the Group Attributes Layout on a target node column in Cytoscape Desktop. All target nodes are grouped and sorted as expected. The source nodes are also grouped in a circle which is desired, I just cannot figure out how to get those (source nodes) in a custom order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy -- just start by selecting your target nodes, then doing the layout using "Selected Only".  That will only layout your target nodes.  Then repeat the process for your source nodes.